# Call function on v-data-table item

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, vuex, vuetify.js

Suppose I have a object list:

```
[teacher {
   name: '',
   department: 'this is department id',
   .......
   .......
}]
```

I have department as another object:

```
[department {
  id: '',
  name: '',
  ......
  .....
  }]
```

I have implemented getter for department as :

```
state: {
    departments: [],
  },
  getters: {
    getDepartmentById: (state) => (id) => {
        return state.departments.find(d => d.id == id)
      }
  },
```

I am using vuetify `v-data-table` to render the items. Now how do call the `getDepartmentById` function to load department name in the teacher list table. I want to display department name is the teachers list, where now I have department id.

Comment: did you put your header data in the vue data model ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use this piece of code for the template:

```
<template>
  <v-data-table
    :headers="headers"
    :items="teachers"
    :items-per-page="5"
    class="elevation-1"
  ></v-data-table>
</template>
```

And this piece of code for the script:

```
data: () => ({
    headers: [
      {
        text: 'Teacher',
        value: 'name' // Must contain this attribute in each teacher
      },
      {
        text: 'Teacher',
        value: 'departmentName' // Must contain this attribute in each teacher
      }
    ],
    teachers: [
    ]
}),
methods: {
    created: async() => {
        const teachersJson = await fetch(...) // call to an API
        this.teachers = teachersJson
                           .map(teacher => 
                             ({ 
                               ...teacher, // Association, same as Object.assign
                               departmentName: this.getDepartmentName(teacher.department)
                             })
                           )
    },
    getDepartmentName: (id) => {
        const department = this.$store.state.departmentsStore.findById(id)
        return department && departname.name
    }
}
```

Comment: I am using axios to call the api. On `created` hook I am calling `const teacherJson = this.get_teacher_list()`, `get_teacher_list` is action mapped using `mapAction` of `vuex` and done as per your code above. But I am getting `teacherJson.map is not a function` error in console.

Comment: This is because an action don't have a return, you must associate the call to a state variable and then create a getter to access its value